# Error when trying to use DroidBox

Tags: android

I am researching how to analyze the application Android use [DroidBox](http://code.google.com/p/droidbox/). But when start analyzing :

`./droidbox.sh file.apk`

get error as follows:

```
android@honeynet:~/tools/droidbox$ ./droidbox.sh a.apk
./droidbox.sh: line 3: adb: command not found
./droidbox.sh: line 3: adb: command not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "scripts/droidbox.py", line 233, in <module>
   call(['adb', 'logcat', '-c'])
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
   return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
   raise child_exception
0SError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's the problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: adb cames from android SDK install SDK and/or setup PATH

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear - you don't have `adb` in your path.

Easiest way to get `adb` is to download Android SDK. `adb` is located in `platform-tools` folder.

In fact, *droidbox* front page [mentions this](http://code.google.com/p/droidbox/#Deploying_release_candidate). So you've probably missed that.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/tools/
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you do not have the Android SDK tools installed, or your `PATH` is not set up correctly. See [Installing the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and be sure to check out the section "How to update your PATH" under Step 5.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to the profile to add these two paths as follows:

```
cd etc
sudo vim ~/.profile
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/tools/
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```